# saprfc with PHP 7.1 on Linux 16.04 not connecting with SAP server

Tags: saprfc

We are trying to install saprfc with PHP 7.1 on Linux 16.04. We get the library from https://sourceforge.net but it is only compatible with PHP 5.3 and we are unable to load the extension in PHP, we followed all the instructions.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you using [the latest source tarball](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/saprfc/saprfc-1.4.1.tar.gz) and which installation method did you try ? Rebuild PHP with saprfc extension included or build saprfc extension as dynamic module without rebuilding PHP? What kind of error do you get?